# Creating a dynamic Column series chart with Syncfusion

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am having an issue with SFChart part of Syncfusion where I am trying to create a Column Series chart. Currently I am just trying to instantiate the SfChart. I should be just getting a blank x and y columns but I am recieiving an error.

```cs
public partial class SurveyVisualView : ContentPage
    {

        public SurveyVisualView()
        {
            SfChart chart = new SfChart();

            //Initializing Primary Axis
            CategoryAxis primaryAxis = new CategoryAxis();

            chart.PrimaryAxis = primaryAxis;

            //Initializing Secondary Axis
            NumericalAxis secondaryAxis = new NumericalAxis();

            chart.SecondaryAxis = secondaryAxis;

            InitializeComponent();

            this.Content = chart;
        }
    }
```

and I get the error when I do `this.Content =  chart;`

with the error `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'`

I am currently just following this guide from Syncfusion

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/charts/getting-started

I am also testing this through Andriod. I can also create a graph within the xaml but I need to create it within the C# for Dynamic column series.

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed your query and the Xamarin.Forms Syncfusion SfChart working fine at our end.  Also, we have prepared the simple sample based on your requirement “Create column chart dynamically” for your reference. Please find the sample from the below link.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ChartSample-502602445

You can get the Xamarin.Forms SfChart getting started sample from the below link
https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/xamarin.forms-sfchart

Also, you can get the demo sample from the below link
https://github.com/syncfusion/xamarin-demos/tree/master/Forms/Chart/Chart/Samples

For more details, please refer the below link.
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/charts/getting-started